# Connecting points of the boundary by interior points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $U$ be an open path-connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\overline{U}$ is path-connected. Assume that $U$ is regular, that is, $U = \mathrm{int}(\overline{U})$.

Let $x, y \in \partial U$. Is it true that there exists a curve $\alpha \colon [0,1] \to \overline{U}$ such that $\alpha(0) = x$, $\alpha(1) = y$ and $\alpha(t) \in U$ for every $t \in (0, 1)$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample: there is no path from bottom left corner to upper right corner within the domain, even though the domain is regular and the closure is path-connected.

[image: counterexample]

Formal description: 
$$
U=\{(x,y) : 0<x<1, \  \sin^2 (\log x)<y<2 \}
$$
(I find that $\sin(\log x)$ makes a nicer curve that the more traditional $\sin(1/x)$.)